# Can I auto shrink my text below my picture just use html and css?

Tags: html, css

I hit a need to auto shrink my text wrapper width below image.

for example:

```
<figure>
    <img src="mypicture.jpg" />
    <figcaption>
        This is a long description.This is a long description.This is a long description.
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Now I want to have a `border` around `img` and `figcaption`, because I have lots of images with different width. So I want to auto shrink the `figcaption` width to fit the image's width. That is if I have a image with width 100px, then I want my `figcaption` 100px too.

Can you tell me if I can do this without js, just use pure html and css?

Comment: Floating figure will probably do it, but it will affect your layout. Also, you could set figure to display: inline-block;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does need some tricks.
You can set the container display to **table** and give it a small width. It will auto align its content width (like a table).

Here is a [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8jwaU/)

Answer (score 0):

```
figure {
    display: table;
}
.page-content figure figcaption {
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
}
```

This accomplish things. @Chris Lee's answer is correct if i specify the fixed image using css. For my situation, i don't want to specify each image's width, because it amount is large and their width is random.

The top css works good for me.